# armadillo max/min function handling of NaN?

Tags: c++, armadillo

arma::max and arma::min seem to provide unexpected results when fed a vector containing all NAN values.    Instead of returning NaN, the min/max functions return +/- inf.   Is this a bug in the library, or expected behavior?

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    arma::vec v(2);
    v[0] = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    v[1] = std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN();
    std::cout << arma::max(v) << " " << arma::min(v) << std::endl;
    // output:  -inf inf 
    std::cout << std::max(v[0], v[1]) << " " << std::min(v[0],v[1]) << std::endl;
    // output:  -inf inf
```

}

For reference, GNU octave:

```
octave:1> min([nan,nan])
ans = NaN
octave:2> max([nan,nan])
ans = NaN
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's up to each library as to how they want to handle this. [Armadillo doesn't seem to document their choice](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#min_and_max), but it's a perfectly reasonable and valid one. I see no reason to assume it's a library bug.

Comment: I expect it's the same that you get if you call it with an empty sequence.